# Protocol 'BaseListPresenter' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, associated-types

I am defining a protocol that has certain functions and variables

```
protocol BaseListPresenter {
    associatedtype T
    var values: [T] {get}
}

extension BaseListPresenter {

    public func count() -> Int {
        return values.count
    }

    public func valueAtIndex(index: Int) -> T? {
        return values[index]
    }
}
```

Now, I want to use this in a class:

```
class X: UIViewController {
    var listPresenter: BaseListPresenter? // HERE it gives me error

    // some other functions and variables here
}
```

Got Error in above saying: Protocol 'BaseListPresenter' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Now, I define sub-class of X:

```
class Y: X {
    func setPresenter() {
        self.listPresenter = UsersPresenter() // UsersPresenter confirms BaseListPresenter protocol with value's type "User"
    }
    // many more functions below
}

class Z: X {
    func setPresenter() {
        self.listPresenter = RoomsPresenter() // RoomsPresenter confirms BaseListPresenter protocol with value's type "Room"
    }
     // many more functions below
}
```

I have achieved solution from ([Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associatedType requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36348061/protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-because-it-has-self-or-associa)) already by creating UsersPresenter and RoomsPresenter. However, I want to create BaseListPresenter type variable which will take different types of value in X (a UIViewController); once Room and next time User depending on subclass of X.

How can I solve this issue and use as I want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associatedType requirements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36348061/protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-because-it-has-self-or-associa)

Comment: I have achieved that already by creating UsersPresenter and RoomsPresenter. However, I want to create BaseListPresenter type variable in X which will take different types of value once Room and next time User depending on subclass of X.

Comment: I have an instance of Class Y.  What data type is `my_y.listPresenter.values[0]`?  If I had an instance of class Z, what would be the data type of `my_z.listPresenter.values[0]`? in Class X what is the type of self.listPresenter.values[0]? Even if its understood in Y an Z its still ambiguous associatedType in X. So the use of `BaseListPresenter` is ambiguous much as described in that other question.

Comment: its User for my_y
its Room for my_z

Comment: can I make X understand type of associatedType of BaseListPresenter from its subclass Y and Z?

Comment: right.  It's ambiguous for every potential use case in class X an therefore is not type safe and is an error.

Comment: So, I cant achieve what I want to? Is there any other alternative way?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, that the associated type of your protocol has to be determined when the protocol is used somewhere. In your implementation of class `X`, the compilator has no idea, what type the `T` is.

I would implement it this way:

```
class X<TPresenter : BaseListPresenter>: UIViewController {
    var listPresenter: TPresenter? // HERE it gives me error

    // some other functions and variables here
}
```

Then specialize `X` when derive:

```
class Y: X<UsersPresenter> {
    func setPresenter() {
        self.listPresenter = UsersPresenter() // UsersPresenter confirms BaseListPresenter protocol with value's type "User"
    }
    // many more functions below
}

class Z: X<RoomsPresenter> {
    func setPresenter() {
        self.listPresenter = RoomsPresenter() // RoomsPresenter confirms BaseListPresenter protocol with value's type "Room"
    }
     // many more functions below
}
```

This construct works.

Note: Using generics in UIViewController derived classes caused me some troubles  about an year ago. Xcode/compiler was somehow unable to link the generic controller with the scene in storyboard. It did not cause compile errors, but it did not work during runtime - spent hours of diagnosing.