# Variable that conforms to a protocol that has a generic function

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I have a protocol that looks like this:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
   associatedtype SpeedType
   var name: String {get set}
   func forward(_: SpeedType)
}
```

I made 2 simple classes that conform to this protocol:

```
class A: MyProtocol {
   typealias SpeedType = Double
   var name: String

   init(name:String) {
       self.name = name
   }

   func forward(_ s: Double) {
       print("Moving \(s) km/h")
   }
}

class B: MyProtocol {
   typealias SpeedType = Int
   var name: String

   init(name:String) {
       self.name = name
   }

   func forward(_ s: Int) {
       print("Moving \(s) km/h")
   }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to be able to declare a variable of type *MyProtocol*, and initialize it later like so:

```
let x: Bool = true
var person: MyProtocol
if x {
   person = A(name: "Robot")
} else {
   person = B(name: "Human")
}
```

Before I made **forward()** method "generic" I was able to do this, however now I am getting the next error: 
**Protocol "MyProtocol" can only be used as  generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirement.**

So my goal is to have a method *forward()* that can take as an argument parameter of a type that I specify, and also be able to declare a variable of a type that conforms to my protocol.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associatedType requirements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36348061/protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-because-it-has-self-or-associa)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swift doesn't allow this.

Here's why: you don't know anything about the type of argument `person.forward(_:)` takes. There is no way to call it. `MyProtocol` essentially defines an open-ended set of **independent** types.

If you don't want to be able to call `person.forward(_:)`, and you just want to be able to access the non-generic `person.name` property, then split your protocol into a base, non-generic protocol defining `name`, and a sub-protocol that adds the generic `forward(_:)` method.

```
protocol NamedThing {
    var name: String {get set}
}

protocol MovableNamedThing: NamedThing {
    associatedtype SpeedType
    func forward(_: SpeedType)
}

class A: MovableNamedThing {
    typealias SpeedType = Double
    var name: String

    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func forward(_ s: Double) {
        print("Moving \(s) km/h")
    }
}

class B: MovableNamedThing {
    typealias SpeedType = Int
    var name: String

    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func forward(_ s: Int) {
        print("Moving \(s) km/h")
    }
}

let x: Bool = true
var person: NamedThing
if x {
    person = A(name: "Robot")
} else {
    person = B(name: "Human")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Interesting solution, I didn't even think about it.

Comment: And is there any way to be able to call forward(_:) method on a person variable?

Comment: No. I already answered that question in the second paragraph of my answer. I don't know how to say it any more clearly.