# Return a many types with only one function

Tags: swift

I search, how I can return a many types with only one function.

**Model**:

```
//MARK: - MODEL -
class ModelA: NSObject, Model{
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        super.init()
    }

    func build()-> ModelA{
        return self
    }
}

class ModelB: NSObject, Model{

    var pseudo: String
    init(pseudo: String) {
        self.pseudo = pseudo
        super.init()
    }

    func build()-> ModelB{
        return self
    }
}
```

My **protocol**:

```
protocol Model{
    associatedtype T
    func build()-> T
}
```

and my **enum**:

```
enum Api{

    case a
    case b

    func request()->Model{
        switch self {
        case .a: return ModelA(name: "Test")
        case .b: return ModelB(pseudo: "Ok")
        }
    }
}
```

But when I build, I have this error:

> Playground execution failed: error: MyPlayground.playground:52:21: error: protocol 'Model' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
>   func request()->Model{

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36350283/4042468), you have to use protocols with associated type as generic constraints.

```
func request<T: Model>() -> T {
    switch self {
    case .a:
        return ModelA(name: "") as! T
    case .b:
        return ModelB(pseudo: "") as! T
    }
}
```

Comment: While this seems to work, I think the type `T` must be declare as `typealias`, else it will yell error that the caller wont know what's type `T`, better is just return `Any` or `AnyObject` and check if it conform the protocol

Comment: If I try your code, Playground failed because 'T' it a generic parameter, and so I can't run 'build()'

Comment: @Tj3n can you explain what will you typealias it to and where?

Comment: @Tj3n Because I do not think we can typealias to one class because the function is returning two different classes. On the other hand, regarding the error you mentioned, if you let compiler to infer the type on the caller side, it will give error but if you explicitly define, it will not create a problem. `let abc: Api = .a; let a: ModelA = abc.request()`

Comment: @kerry my bad, not typealias, just the whole class need to know what's `T`, like `SomeClass<T : Model >`, but not sure in this case, where the OP have multiple class, as the OP reply, it bring error when use, but it fine when declare

Comment: @Horusdunord I have tested it on playground and it is working fine. Can u paste your complete updated code where you are using my solution?

Comment: @kerry Yes, but you cast your variable ... I need receipt dynamic type

Comment: @Horusdunord I am casting it to T here. How is that not dynamic?

Comment: The idea would be to have an enum (case = API endpoint), which returns an object according to the request
 
exemple :
 
- case getUsers, getUser(id: Int),getProfile(id: Int) ... 
- request() : Request API
- build() : Convert JSON to Object
 
Api.getUsers.request().build() return : [User]
Api.getUser(id: 9).request().build() return : User
Api.getProfile(id: 1).request().build() return : Profile etc etc

Comment: @Horusdunord I understood what you want from this. And this will work. So if you make a request to API "a", it will fetch ModelA and similarly for API "b", it will deserialise to ModelB. The only thing you have to take care is that the caller should specify the type explicitly and since the caller always knows which API it is calling, it can specify the correct type.

Comment: @Horusdunord If that solves your problem, lets close it by accepting the answer by clicking on the tick mark

Comment: @kerry ok ok, but you think it impossible to have a response with a correctly type, without dev intervention ? for example if i dev a SDK, and you use this, so you should cast all responses of call

Comment: @Horusdunord We are not casting here anything. I am just specifying the type while calling the method which I already know. This is like `let marks: Int = 5; let marks = 5`. I already know that `marks` is Int but still in the second example I ask compiler to infer the type. So both works. But when there are generics, compiler cannot infer it directly, so we specify the type.

Comment: @Kerry Yes of course, but I wanted to say, dev directly use :

let profil = Api.getProfile.request().build() 
self.titleLabel.text = profil.username

Comment: @Horusdunord No, I don't think there is a way to let compiler automatically infer type in this case.

Comment: @Horusdunord Lets continue this over chat if you have more to discuss else close this question.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what `Self` is for (rather than using an explicit associated type):

```
protocol Model{
    func build() -> Self
}

class ModelA: NSObject, Model{
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        super.init()
    }

    func build() -> Self {
        return self
    }
}
```