# Implementing generic protocols Error by compiler

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I am trying to use generic protocols in my Application. Code which I am trying to use is something like this.

```
protocol BaseProtocol {
  associatedtype PresenterType
  var presenter: PresenterType? { get set }
}

protocol PresenterProtocol {
  associatedtype View
  var view: View? { get set }
}

protocol ChildPresenter: PresenterProtocol where View == ChildProtocol {

}

protocol ChildProtocol: BaseProtocol where PresenterType == ChildPresenter {

}


class A: ChildProtocol {
  var presenter: ChildPresenter?
}
```

Compiler is throwing error while conforming to ChildProtocol

> error: protocol 'ChildPresenter' can only be used as a generic
>   constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements   var
>   presenter: ChildPresenter?

I am not getting why compiler is throwing this error when I have already cleared my associateType.

Comment: In case you didn't understand why you got an error, I added an explanation in my answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associatedType requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36348061/protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-because-it-has-self-or-associa)

Answer (score 3):

As the error says, `ChildPresenter` can olny be used as a generic, so you have to place it on the declaration of the class, eg. `class A<T: ChildPresenter> : ChildProtocol`

```
protocol BaseProtocol {
    associatedtype PresenterType
    var presenter: PresenterType? { get set }
}

protocol PresenterProtocol {
    associatedtype View
    var view: View? { get set }
}

protocol ChildPresenter: PresenterProtocol where View == ChildProtocol {

}

protocol ChildProtocol: BaseProtocol {

}


class A<T: ChildPresenter> : ChildProtocol {
    var presenter: T?
    func foo(bar: T) {

    }
}
```

You also can use `ChildPresenter` instead of `T`, like this

```
class A<ChildPresenter> : ChildProtocol {
    var presenter: ChildPresenter?
}
```

At first it seems that this limits a little bit your class `A`, because you have to specify the type of ChilPresenter before initialization, and it can't be modified later, but this is necessary because `ChildPresenter` has a associated type.

You can see that without the generic you could get into trouble, imagine that `BaseProtocol` had one more property

```
protocol BaseProtocol {
    associatedtype PresenterType
    var presenter: PresenterType? { get set }
    var presented: PresenterType? { get set }
}
```

Both `presenter` and `presented` have to be the same type, because you said it here

[image: BaseProtocol declaration with Types highlighted]

And `class A` would have one more property too:

```
class A<ChildPresenter> : ChildProtocol {
    var presenter: ChildPresenter?
    var presented: ChildPresenter?
}
```

This way, you guarantee that both `presenter` and `presented` will have always the same type, because you choose that type when you created an object of `A`, eg. `let a = A<Foo>()`

[image: A declaration with types hightlighted]

Without the generic, it would look something like this

```
class A: ChildProtocol {
    var presenter: ChildPresenter?
    var presented: ChildPresenter?
}
```

And in this way, `presenter` could be of type `Foo` and `presented` could be of type `Bar`. So you end up with a paradox. Thats why you need to set the generic type in `A`'s declaration.

Comment: On doing 'class A<ChildPresenter> : ChildProtocol {
    var presenter: ChildPresenter?
}'

Comment: Compiler is throwing  error: 'ChildProtocol' requires the types 'ChildPresenter' and 'ChildPresenter' be equivalent
class A<ChildPresenter>: ChildProtocol {  note: requirement specified as 'Self.PresenterType' == 'ChildPresenter' [with Self = A<ChildPresenter>]
class A<ChildPresenter>: ChildProtocol {

Comment: You have to remove the `where` clause on `ChildProtocol`'s declaration