# Swift define associated type in subprotocol

Tags: swift, protocols

Let's say I have the following protocol:

```
protocol Driver {
    associatedtype Car
}
```

And than a protocol inheriting from `Driver`, explicitly setting `Car` to be of type `RaceCar`.

```
protocol RacingDriver: Driver {
    typealias Car = RaceCar
}
```

Why do I still get the error

> protocol 'RacingDriver' can only be used as a generic constraint
>   because it has Self or associated type requirements

when doing `var driver: RacingDriver` ?

***Background story:***

Essentially what I would like to have is a variable which can be of any type conforming to `Driver`, as long as that type has `Car` defined to be a `RaceCar`.

Example:

```
protocol Driver {
    associatedtype Car
}

protocol RacingDriver: Driver {
    typealias Car = RaceCar
}

struct NascarDriver: RacingDriver {}
struct IndyDriver: RacingDriver {}

struct NormalDriver: Driver {}

var racingDriver: RacingDriver // This could be either a NascarDriver or IndyDriver but not a NormalDriver!
```

How could I achieve this?

**Is there a way around this other than type-erasure?**

*I would like to avoid subclassing from a `RacingDriver` base class.*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associatedType requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36348061/protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-because-it-has-self-or-associa). For a solution, you should look into _type erasure_, which also has been discussed extensively [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+type+erasure). [This](http://robnapier.net/erasure) blog post explaining type erasure can also prove useful.

Comment: Please see my edited answer! But I guess the answer is a NO.

Comment: AFAIK until Swift will have generic protocols (which was deemed unlikely in the [Generics Manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#conditional-conformances-)), the only solution for using a protocol with associated types as a concrete type is through type erasure.