# Protocol can an only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

Following on from an answer to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50346052/protocol-extending-encodable-or-codable-does-not-conform-to-it), I have 2 protocols…

```
protocol Filters: Encodable { 
}

protocol QueryParameters: Encodable {
    associatedtype T: Filters
    var page: Int { get }
    var filters: T { get }
}
```

and then for a type `Transaction`, I have…

```
struct TransactionFilters: Filters {
    var isWithdrawal: Bool
}

struct TransactionParamters<T: Filters>: QueryParameters {
    var page: Int
    var filters: T
}
```

All good so far.

Next I add a protocol, `Filterable`, and I'd like any type that conforms to `Filterable` to be able to return parameters, like this…

```
protocol Filterable {
    func parameters() -> QueryParameters
}

struct Transactions: Filterable {
    func parameters() -> QueryParameters {
        let transactionFilters = TransactionFilters(isWithdrawal: true)
        return TransactionParamters(page: 1, filters: transactionFilters)
    }
}
```

but I end up with…

> error: protocol 'QueryParameters' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

This seems a pretty straightforward requirement, but I've spent 2 days trying all combinations I could think of to get it to work. Now I'm finally admitting defeat.

What do I need to do to resolve this?

Comment: Maybe there is some usefull information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075977/using-delegates-on-generic-protocol

Comment: `QueryParameters` is a protocol, not a type. You don't seem to have defined it as a `struct` or `class` etc. Thus `func parameters() -> QueryParameters` does not make sense. I am not an expert on these things however, so I'm open to correction.

Comment: @Chris - I want the func to return an object that conforms to the `QueryParameters` protocol. I've spent so long looking at this I've gone code-blind. Can't tell what's right or wrong any more!

Comment: You could declare `Parameter` as a `struct` and declare its conformance to `QueryParameters` in its declaration: `struct Parameter: QueryParameters { }` and then function could be `func parameters() -> Parameter`

Comment: Code-blind is my basic state! :)

Comment: The bottom line is you have an `associatedtype` and nowhere in your code do you tell what type it should be.

Comment: @AuRis Any idea how I resolve that?

Comment: Have a look at [Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self of associatedType requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36348061/protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-because-it-has-self-or-associa)

Comment: There are a few problems: `QueryParameters` declares `get` variables, but your struct doesn't conform to that requirement, also it is unknown how you can initialize the `Filters` object as it never becomes a type. If I have time I'll write an answer later.

Comment: @AuRis `TransactionParameters` does conform to `QueryParameters` - it has `page` and `filters`. Am I missing something? And `filters` is set to `TransactionFilters` - a concrete type

Comment: `TransactionParameters` does not conform to `QueryParameters` because in `QueryParameters` both properties are declared as `get` and in `TransactionParameters` they are `set` and `get`.

Comment: @AshleyMills please check my answer and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little late, but I think it's still a good exercise to come up with a clean solution for your problem.

Within the `Filterable` protocol, you can't use the protocol type `QueryParameters` as a return type because `QueryParameters` has an `associatedtype`. Also, it's not really what you want, because returning a protocol type doesn't mean it conforms to itself (ie. `QueryParameters` type doesn't conform to `QueryParameters`).

Instead, what you need to do is create an `associatedtype` that conforms to the protocol `QueryParameters` to be used as a return type:

```
protocol Filterable {
    associatedtype T : QueryParameters
    func parameters() -> T
}
```

Then you can make `Transactions` conform to `Filterable` using the same function you have in your question but returning the [opaque type](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OpaqueTypes.html) `some QueryParameters` rather than the protocol type `QueryParameters`. This way you can return any type that conforms to `QueryParameters` which is what you really wanted to do:

```
struct Transactions: Filterable {
    func parameters() -> some QueryParameters {
        let transactionFilters = TransactionFilters(isWithdrawal: true)
        return TransactionParameters(page: 1, filters: transactionFilters)
    }
}
```

I hope you find that helpful. BTW, I fixed the typo in `TransactionParameters` in my answer :)

Answer (score 6):

As I mentioned in the comment. What is missing in your code is that the `associatedtype` never actually becomes a type. Nowhere in the code in one of your `structs` you assign the type to the `associatedtype`. If you want a generic `filterable` functionality you could do something along those lines:

```
// Your generic Filters with required properties
protocol Filters: Encodable {
    var isWithdrawal: Bool { get }
    init(isWithdrawal: Bool)
}

// Your generic query parameters
protocol QueryParameters: Encodable {
    associatedtype F: Filters
    var page: Int { get }
    var filters: F { get }

    init(page: Int, filters: Filters)
}

// Filterable protocol will eventually accept any types conforming to Filters and QueryParameters
protocol Filterable {
    associatedtype F: Filters
    associatedtype P: QueryParameters

    func parameters() -> P
}

// This is your generic Transactions struct
// With this you will be able to pass other types that meet the constraints
struct Transactions<ParameterType: QueryParameters>: Filterable {
    typealias P = ParameterType
    typealias F = ParameterType.F

    func parameters() -> ParameterType {
        return P(page: 1, filters: F(isWithdrawal: true))
    }
}
```

You're done with the generic stuff. Now you can create different model objects which conform to your protocols

```
struct TransactionFilters: Filters {
    private(set) var isWithdrawal: Bool // Conforming to filters
}

struct TransactionParameters<FilterType: Filters>: QueryParameters {
    // Telling what type is the object that conforms to Filters
    typealias F = FilterType
    var page: Int
    var filters: FilterType

    init(page: Int, filters: Filters) {
        self.page = page
        self.filters = filters as! F
    }
}
```

Create your transactions object like this:

```
let transactions = Transactions<TransactionParameters<TransactionFilters>>()
print(transactions.parameters().page)
print(transactions.parameters().filters.isWithdrawal)
```

You can create more types of QueryParameters and Filters

```
struct SomeOtherParameters<FilterType: Filters>: QueryParameters {
    // You can do custom stuff in your SomeOtherParameters struct
    // e.g. add an offset to page
    typealias F = FilterType
    var page: Int
    var filters: FilterType

    init(page: Int, filters: Filters) {
        self.page = page + 100
        self.filters = filters as! F
    }
}

// Your special filter that always returns false
struct SomeOtherFilters: Filters {
    init(isWithdrawal: Bool) {}

    var isWithdrawal: Bool {
        return false
    }
}

let transactionsWithDifferentFilters = Transactions<SomeOtherParameters<SomeOtherFilters>>()

// You can combine any types that conform to you declared protocols
let evenMoreTransactions = Transactions<SomeOtherParameters<TransactionFilters>>()
print(evenMoreTransactions.parameters().page)
```