# Specifying associated type via protocol inheritance with generic where clause in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

Compiling following code:

```
protocol Foo {
    associatedtype Element
}

protocol IntFoo: Foo where Element == Int {
}

struct A: IntFoo {
}

let intFoo: IntFoo = A()
```

produces error message: `Protocol 'IntFoo' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`.

Didn't I just specify an associated type requirement or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36348061/protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-because-it-has-self-or-associa