# Protocols with Associated Types in array - alternative solutions

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

Consider an example:

```
protocol CellConfigurator {
  var cellClass: UICollectionViewCell.Type {get}
  func configure(cell: UICollectionViewCell)
}

class AppleCell: UICollectionViewCell {
  let title = UILabel()
}

class AppleCellConfigurator: CellConfigurator {
  let cellClass: UICollectionViewCell.Type = AppleCell.self
  func configure(cell: UICollectionViewCell) {
    guard let cell = cell as? AppleCell else {return}
    cell.title.text = "AAPL"
  }
}
```

I can use the aforementioned pattern to encapsulate the actual type of the `UICollectionViewCell`, use it as follows (pseudocode):

```
func cellAt(indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  let configurator = configurators[indexPath]
  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(identifier: String(describing: configurator.cellClass))
  configurator.configure(cell)
  return cell
}
```

I'm looking forward to getting rid of the necessity to type-cast the cell in every conforming to `CellConfigurator`, for example, using protocols with associated types:

```
protocol CellConfigurator {
  associatedtype Cell
  func configure(cell: Cell)
}

class AppleCell: UICollectionViewCell {
  let title = UILabel()
}

class AppleCellConfigurator: CellConfigurator {
  typealias Cell = AppleCell
  func configure(cell: Cell) {
    cell.title.text = "AAPL"
  }
}
```

However, I can't hold them together in an array due to an error: "Protocol 'SomeProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements".

Is there any way to achieve the two goals:

1. Having a function with `UICollectionViewCell` parameter type for any `CellConfigurator`?
2. Having a concrete type inside the function of a particular configurator

Comment: I think you can create a generic base class that conform to `CellConfigurator` and then `AppleCellConfigurator` will inherit from that class.

Comment: @Kamran I think it's a good case for type erasure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use associatedtype in you're CellConfigurator:

```
protocol CellConfigurator: class {
    associatedtype CellType where CellType: UICollectionViewCell

    func configure(cell: CellType)
}

class AppleCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let title = UILabel()
}

class AppleCellConfigurator: CellConfigurator {
    typealias CellType = AppleCell

    func configure(cell: CellType) {
        cell.title.text = "AAPL"
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach doesn't solve a problem, it's impossible to store two different `CellConfigurator`'s in array.

Comment: @RichardTopchiy it will explains: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36348061/protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-because-it-has-self-or-associa