# Swift: Protocol With associatedType

Tags: swift, protocols, associated-types

I have a question about Protocol with associated type, why I can not make the protocol a type of my instance for example:
[image]

I know I can use Type Erasure to fix the issue, but why protocol with an associated type does not like to be a type of an instance, and if you will say because the associated type is also used as a constraint, well I want to implement the properties inside the protocol not inside its extensions since protocol extensions has the power to control who can access its properties, why we still have this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associatedType requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36348061/protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-because-it-has-self-or-associa)

Comment: it made me even more confused

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of articles and answers ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36348061/protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-because-it-has-self-or-associa)) out there describing why but in summary, It needs `associatedtype`. Variables can not have an `associatedtype`. So alongside with *Type Erasure* method (that you don't want), you can simply make it **opaque** with adding `some` keyword to the type:

```
var objectA: some ProtocolA = A()
```

Comment: Do you have any further questions?