# How to initialize stored property which is of type associatedtype protocol

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, associated-types

```
protocol Identifiable {
    associatedtype ID
    func identifier() -> ID
}

protocol PersonProtocol: Identifiable {
    var name: String { get }
    var age: Int { get }
}

class Person: PersonProtocol {
    let name: String
    let age: Int

    init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }

    func identifier() -> String {
        return "\(name)_\(age)"
    }
}
```

I tried to a declare & initialise stored property as `let owner: PersonProtocol` in class `Car` but it gave an error:

> `PersonProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

[image]
Hence I tried following piece of code to do the same, but I am not sure if this is the correct way to do this. 
Need suggestions.

```
class Car<T: PersonProtocol>{
    let owner: T
    init<U: PersonProtocol>(owner: U) where U.ID == String {
        self.owner = owner as! T // I am force casting `U` as `T`. is this forcecasting justified ?
    }

    func getID() -> String {
        owner.identifier() as! String // is this forcecasting justified ?
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associatedType requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36348061/protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-because-it-has-self-or-associa)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Car<U,T: PersonProtocol> where T.ID == U{
    let owner: T
    init(owner: T) {
        self.owner = owner
    }

    func getID() -> U {
        owner.identifier()
    }
}
```

```
let person = Person(name: "John Snow", age: 34)
let car = Car<String, Person>(owner: person)
```