# How to store a property that conforms to the ListStyle protocol

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, protocols

Currently I'm setting the `listStyle` with the `.listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())` modifier.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ListView()
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    let data = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six"]
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(data, id: \.self) { word in
                Text(word)
            }
        }
        .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

I want to make a property inside `ListView` to store the `ListStyle`. The problem is that `ListStyle` is a protocol, and I get:

> Protocol 'ListStyle' can only be used as a generic constraint because
> it has Self or associated type requirements

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ListView(listStyle: InsetGroupedListStyle())
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    var listStyle: ListStyle /// this does not work
    let data = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six"]
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(data, id: \.self) { word in
                Text(word)
            }
        }
        .listStyle(listStyle)
    }
}
```

I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36348061/14351818), but I don't know what `ListStyle`'s `associatedtype` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use generics to make your `listStyle` be of *some* `ListStyle` type:

```
struct ListView<S>: View where S: ListStyle {
    var listStyle: S
    let data = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six"]
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(data, id: \.self) { word in
                Text(word)
            }
        }
        .listStyle(listStyle)
    }
}
```