# Make instance of struct with a generic when the generic has a default value

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I wanted to store `ListStyle` in a property inside `SupportOpts`, so I added the `<S>` and `where S: ListStyle` to the struct declaration (from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64418909/14351818)).

```
struct SupportOpts<S> where S: ListStyle {
    var title: String = "Placeholder"
    var listStyle: S = InsetGroupedListStyle() as! S /// had to put an `as! S` or else it couldn't compile
}
```

I can make an instance of it like this:

```
let options: SupportOpts = SupportOpts(
    title: "Title",
    listStyle: InsetGroupedListStyle()
)
```

But, when I remove `InsetGroupedListStyle()` (I already set a default value inside `SupportOpts`):

```
let options: SupportOpts = SupportOpts(
    title: "Title"
)
```

I get:

> Generic parameter 'S' could not be inferred, Explicitly specify the generic arguments to fix this issue [Fix]

So I pressed the Fix button, and it's now expecting a `S: ListStyle`:
[image: error "Cannot find type '<#S: ListStyle#>' in scope"]

What should I put here?

```
let options: SupportOpts = SupportOpts<ListStyle>(title: "Title")
/// Error: Value of protocol type 'ListStyle' cannot conform to 'ListStyle'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

let options: SupportOpts = SupportOpts<S>(title: "Title")
/// Error: Cannot find type 'S' in scope (well that's kind of obvious...)

let options: SupportOpts = SupportOpts<InsetGroupedListStyle>(title: "Title")
/// this works...
```

Do I have to specify `SupportOpts<InsetGroupedListStyle>(title: "Title")`, even if I already set a default inside `SupportOpts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell that something has gone wrong when you needed to add `as!`. That isn't the right approach. Consider the case if someone chose a different `S`:

```
let options = SupportOpts<InsetListStyle>(title: "Title")
```

This would have to crash.

Instead, you want an extension to make things more convenient.

```
struct SupportOpts<S> where S: ListStyle {
    var title: String = "Placeholder"
    var listStyle: S     // No default value here
}
```

Your goal is to have an `init` that just takes title, so you add that:

```
extension SupportOpts where S == InsetGroupedListStyle {
    init(title: String) {
        self.init(title: title, listStyle: InsetGroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

And type inference will work out the rest:

```
let options = SupportOpts(title: "Title")
```

Comment: But what if I have another struct that contains `var options: SupportOpts` (just the type, no initialization)? It doesn't work... I get "Reference to generic type 'SupportOpts' requires arguments in <...>"

Comment: Ok, I fixed it with `struct OtherStruct<S>: View where S: ListStyle { var options: SupportOpts<S> }`, not sure if that's the right way though

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You can also write it `struct OtherStruct<S: ListStyle>: View`. The two are identical.