# SwiftUI - Wrap ListStyle in an enum and translate it back to ListStyle

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swiftui

I'm working on a library, so I want it to be as easily configurable as possible. I put all the configurable options inside `SupportOptions`.

```
struct SupportOptions {
    var text: String = ""
    var listStyle: CustomListStyle = CustomListStyle.insetGroupedListStyle
}
extension SupportOptions {
    
    /**
     Enum wrapper for `ListStyle`
     */
    enum CustomListStyle {
        case defaultListStyle
        case plainListStyle
        case groupedListStyle
        case insetGroupedListStyle
        case insetListStyle
        case sidebarListStyle
    }
}
```

I'm following [@Sweeper's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64627827/14351818) to use an enum to store `ListStyle`, so that's what `CustomListStyle` is for. But I need to translate `CustomListStyle` to an actual `ListStyle`. This is what I have so far:

```
extension List {
    func getStyle<S>(listStyle: SupportOptions.CustomListStyle) -> S {
        switch listStyle {
        case .defaultListStyle:
            return DefaultListStyle() as! S
        case .plainListStyle:
            return PlainListStyle() as! S
        case .groupedListStyle:
            return GroupedListStyle() as! S
        case .insetGroupedListStyle:
            return InsetGroupedListStyle() as! S
        case .insetListStyle:
            return InsetListStyle() as! S
        case .sidebarListStyle:
            return SidebarListStyle() as! S
        }
    }
}
```

But when I use it, I get

> Generic parameter 'S' could not be inferred

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let options = SupportOptions(listStyle: .defaultListStyle)
    
    let data = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen"]
    var body: some View {
        List { /// Error! Generic parameter 'S' could not be inferred
            ForEach(data, id: \.self) { word in
                Text(word)
            }
        }
        .getStyle(listStyle: options.listStyle)
    }
}
```

I tried adding a placeholder type `S`, but the error stayed the same...

```
struct ContentView<S>: View where S: ListStyle {
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return an [opaque type](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OpaqueTypes.html) (`some View`) instead:

```
extension List {
    @ViewBuilder
    func listStyle(for customListStyle: SupportOptions.CustomListStyle) -> some View {
        switch customListStyle {
        case .defaultListStyle:
            listStyle(DefaultListStyle())
        case .plainListStyle:
            listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        case .groupedListStyle:
            listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
        case .insetGroupedListStyle:
            listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
        case .insetListStyle:
            listStyle(InsetListStyle())
        case .sidebarListStyle:
            listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

```
List {
    // ...
}
.listStyle(for: options.listStyle)
```