# Using ternary operator in SwiftUI causes mismatching types error, why?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I currently have been using this `Environment` variable to adjust things for `Dark` and `Light` modes on my app.

> @Environment(.colorScheme) var colorScheme

The problem I'm having is using that `var` to conditionally set a button style. This method works just fine.

```
if colorScheme == .dark {
                    Button("Create Account", action: {
                        
                    }).buttonStyle(CinderDarkButtonStyle(geometry: geometry))
                } else {
                    Button("Create Account", action: {
                        
                    }).buttonStyle(CinderLightButtonStyle(geometry: geometry))
                }
```

However doing it this way causes me to duplicate code all over the place on a relatively simple user interface. Whenever I attempt to do it this way I end up with errors stating that I have mismatched types.

```
Button("Create Account", action: {
                            //DO SOME ACTION
                        }).buttonStyle(
colorScheme == .dark ? 
     CinderDarkButtonStyle(geometry: geometry) :
     CinderLightButtonStyle(geometry: geometry)
)
```

Comment: Is it the extra `)`?

Comment: @Don no, that was a typo, nice catch :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides what [@Don](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9269689/don) said about the extra `)`, `CinderDarkButtonStyle` and `CinderLightButtonStyle` are different structs. They aren't the same type.

What you can do is make a custom function that returns an opaque type, as said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64635065/14351818). Try something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var colorScheme = ColorScheme.dark

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Button("Create Account", action: {
                //DO SOME ACTION
            })
            .buttonStyle(for: colorScheme, geometry: geometry) /// use custom buttonStyle function
        }
    }
}

extension Button {
    @ViewBuilder
    func buttonStyle(for colorScheme: ColorScheme, geometry: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
        switch colorScheme {
        case .light:
            buttonStyle(CinderDarkButtonStyle(geometry: geometry))
        case .dark:
            buttonStyle(CinderLightButtonStyle(geometry: geometry))
        }
    }
}
```

The above switches between a `buttonStyle(CinderDarkButtonStyle(geometry: geometry))` and `buttonStyle(CinderLightButtonStyle(geometry: geometry))` modifier, based on the `colorScheme`.

Answer (score 2):

You get the error because `CinderDarkButtonStyle` and `CinderLightButtonStyle` are, in fact, different types. And, `ButtonStyle` has an associated type, so you can't just to a straight cast to `ButtonStyle`.

If this were a normal `View` and not a `ButtonStyle`, you could use `AnyView` to do some type erasure so that the types would be equivalent.

In this case, it seems like it would be much cleaner just to move the logic about which button style to show inside the custom button style:

```
struct MyTestView : View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Button("Create Account", action: {
                //DO SOME ACTION
            })
            .buttonStyle(CinderButtonStyle(geometry: geometry))
        }
    }
}

struct CinderButtonStyle : ButtonStyle {
    var geometry : GeometryProxy
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) private var colorScheme
    
    @ViewBuilder func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        switch colorScheme {
        case .dark:
            darkBody(configuration: configuration)
        case .light:
            lightBody(configuration: configuration)
        @unknown default:
            lightBody(configuration: configuration)
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder func lightBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label //light modifications
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder func darkBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label //dark modifications
    }
}
```

---

Update, using view modifiers:

```
struct CinderButtonStyle : ButtonStyle {
    var geometry : GeometryProxy
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) private var colorScheme
    
    @ViewBuilder func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        switch colorScheme {
        case .dark:
            lightAndDarkModifications(configuration: configuration)
                .modifier(DarkModifier())
        default:
            lightAndDarkModifications(configuration: configuration)
                .modifier(LightModifier())
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder func lightAndDarkModifications(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
    }
}

struct DarkModifier : ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
    }
}

struct LightModifier : ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
    }
}
```

Comment: This is explanatory, however I do have to ask, what and where should I put universal modifications that relate to both dark and white?

Comment: You'll need to do a `switch` or `if` somewhere, for sure -- it's just a matter of how far abstracted you want it to be. I added an example for using view modifiers. You can still have globally-affected code with `lightAndDarkModifications` and then apply the modifiers conditionally -- you'll still have *some* duplication like your initial question. In this case, it appears in the `makeBody` of the button style -- at least it wouldn't be duplicated in your actual view code all over the place.

Comment: Doing it the method without view modifiers returns only `.light` in the switch statment. Hmmmmmm

Comment: I believe this answer is mostly correct but my SwiftUI experience is limited and I couldn't get it to properly work. I was able to get it to work with the answer below using an opaque type.