# Different .listStyle() on iOS and WatchOS in a reusable component?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'd love to reuse a list layout between iOS and WatchOS, but `InsetGroupedListStyle()` isn't available on WatchOS.

What would be a good way to create a helper that would conditionally return `InsetGroupedListStyle()` on iOS and eg. `PlainListStyle()` on WatchOS?

I tried this, but get an error that I cannot return `ListStyle` (which is probably caused by SwiftUI needing to know a specific type in compile time).

View.swift

```
List {
    // ...
}
.listStyle(MyInsetGroupedListStyle())
```

Helpers.swift

```
public func MyInsetGroupedListStyle() -> ListStyle {
    #if os(watchOS)
        return PlainListStyle()
    #else
        return InsetGroupedListStyle()
    #endif
}
```

Alternate way could be specifying the listStyle inline, but swift doesn't support conditional compilation in expressions:

View.swift

```
List {
    // ...
}
.listStyle(#if os(watchOS) PlainListStyle() #else InsetGroupedListStyle() #endif)
```

Comment: I asked almost the exact same thing a while ago! You need to return an opaque type: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64635065/14351818

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using an extension on View. This allows you to add the `listStyle` modifier with the parameter that you want for the OS that you want.

```
extension View {
    public func customListStyle() -> some View {
        #if os(watchOS)
        return self.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        #else
        return self.listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
        #endif
    }
}
```

You would then use it like this:

```
List {
    // items in list go here
}
.customListStyle()
```

Comment: Thank you for a help with this pattern!

Answer (score 1):

Use

1. an opaque type

```swift
public var myInsetGroupedListStyle: some ListStyle {
  #if os(watchOS)
  PlainListStyle()
  #else
  InsetGroupedListStyle()
  #endif
}
```

2. a closure

```swift
listStyle( {
  #if os(watchOS)
  PlainListStyle()
  #else
  InsetGroupedListStyle()
  #endif
} () )
```

Comment: Thank you! Too bad I had to only choose one answer, as both yours and Andrews are great and useful.