# Swift Struct Inheritance defaults

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, struct

I would like to create my models for my iOS app using struct as I understand it is the appropriate way to do things. I have the following:

```
protocol Exercise: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID { get }
    var name: String { get }
    var type: ExerciseType { get }

}
```

---

```
enum ExerciseType {
    case duration
    case reps
    case rest
}
```

---

```
extension Exercise {
    var id: UUID { UUID() }
}
```

---

```
struct DurationExercise: Exercise {
    let name: String
    let durationInSeconds: Int
    let type: ExerciseType = .duration
    
}
```

---

```
struct RepetionsExercise: Exercise {
    let name: String
    let reps: Int
    let type: ExerciseType = .reps
}
```

---

```
struct RestExercise: Exercise {
    let name: String
    let durationInSeconds: Int
    let type: ExerciseType = .rest
}
```

- Is this extending the proper way to initialize the `id: UUID` using
  protocol + structs?
- Is there a way where I don't have to specify the
  `name: String` in every struct that inherits `Exercise`?
- Or if I want to do something like I should just use `class`?

Comment: What do you mean by initialize just once? One UUID for all structs that conform to that protocol?

Comment: As a computed property it will generate a new UUID every time you call that property.

Comment: No need to create a very similar struct with so many common properties if you have already an enumeration for exercise types

Comment: I agree. This approach is going to come back and bite you because while all of your types implement `Excercise` they are not co-variant. Much better to have a single `Excercise` struct with optional `reps` and `duration` properties.

Comment: `id` is already a required property of `Identifiable` so there is no point to have it in your own protocol.

Comment: I am trying to achieve where `let type = DURATION` would always contain `duration` without having to check if it is `nil`. Otherwise, I am fine creating struct `Exercise` that contains optional `reps` and `duration`.

Comment: You will need to write conditional code either way. Either you have to conditionally unwrap `reps` and `duration` or you are going to have to conditionally downcast variables of type `Exercise` to concrete types. And then what happens when you decide to create a new type of exercise `TimedRepertitionsExercise`?  If have optionals you don't have to change much. If you are using different structs then you now have to test for a new kind of struct. Structs and protocols don't have inheritance and it is a mistake to treat them like they do.

Comment: If you continue with this approach I foresee [Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36348061/protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-because-it-has-self-or-associa) in your future

Comment: Yep, I got the that error. It makes sense what you are saying. I need to wrap my head what struct is exactly, as clearly I do not have a good understanding of it. Thanks for feedback. I'll be using your recommended approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that you have a fixed set of exercise types, it would be simpler to eliminate the protocol entirely:

```
struct Exercise: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var type: ExerciseType
    
    enum ExerciseType {
        case duration(TimeInterval)
        case reps(Int)
        case rest(TimeInterval)
    }
}
```

If you need multiple associated values for one of the types, you might choose to introduce another `struct` to hold the multiple values. Example:

```
struct Exercise: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var type: ExerciseType
    
    enum ExerciseType {
        case duration(TimeInterval)
        case reps(Reps)
        case rest(TimeInterval)
    }
    
    struct Reps {
        var sets: Int
        var repsPerSet: Int
    }
}
```

Comment: I was unaware that I could set enum in this way. Is there a term for defining enum value like so `enum ExerciseType { case duration(TimeInterval) }`? I will give this a try.

Comment: It's called an “associated value”. You can read about it in [“Enumerations” in *The Swift Programming Lanugage*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html).

Comment: More generally, what Swift calls an `enum` is called a “sum type” in the study of programming languages, and is one half of what is called ”algebraic data types” (the other half being a ”product type” which in Swift is a `struct`). Sum types are an essential part of a programming philosophy called “Domain-Driven Design”. The motto of domain-driven design is “make illegal states unrepresentable” (or “make impossible states impossible”). I highly recommend learning about it, because it will make you a better programmer.