# Mocking a generic class in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, xctest, swift-protocols

I have a class for that I want to write unit test. This class has a dependency, which is a generic class, that I want to mock.

This is the class I want to test.

```
class ClassToTest: SomeProtocol {
    
    private let dependency = DependencyClass<AnotherClass>()
    
    init() {
        //Some Code Here
    }
}

class DependencyClass<General: AnotherClassProtocol> {
    func getData(from general: General) -> AnyPublisher<Data, Error> {
        //Some Code Here
    }
}
```

What I tried

```
class ClassToTest: SomeProtocol {
    
    private let dependency: DependencyClassProtocol
    
    init(_ dependency: DependencyClassProtocol = DependencyClass<AnotherClass>()) {
        //Some Code Here
        self. dependency = dependency
    }
}

class DependencyClass<General: AnotherClassProtocol>: DependencyClassProtocol {
    func getData(from general: General) -> AnyPublisher<Data, Error> {
        //Some Code Here
    }
}

protocol DependencyClassProtocol {
    associatedtype General
    func getData(from general: General) -> AnyPublisher<Data, Error> 
}
```

This approach gives me error *"Protocol can an only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements"*.

How can I Mock the DependencyClass to test the exact behaviour of ClassToTest.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36348061/protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-because-it-has-self-or-associa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not removed the generic constraints from the `DependencyClass<General: AnotherClassProtocol>` and also not added the type alias in the class definition. As soon as I did these changes it  worked.

```
import Combine
import Foundation

protocol DependencyClassProtocol {
    associatedtype General
    func getData(from general: General) -> AnyPublisher<Data, Error>?
}

class ClassToTest: SomeProtocol {
    
    private let dependency: any DependencyClassProtocol
    
    init(_ dependency: any DependencyClassProtocol = DependencyClass()) {
        //Some Code Here
        self.dependency = dependency
    }
}

class DependencyClass: DependencyClassProtocol {
    typealias General = AnotherClassProtocol
    
    func getData(from general: General) -> AnyPublisher<Data, Error>? {
        return nil
    }
}

class MockDependencyClass: DependencyClassProtocol {
    typealias General = AnotherClassProtocol
    
    func getData(from general: General) -> AnyPublisher<Data, Error>? {
        return nil
    }
}

protocol AnotherClassProtocol {
    
}

protocol SomeProtocol {
    
}

class AnotherClass: AnotherClassProtocol {}

let ctt = ClassToTest(MockDependencyClass())
```