# Protocol 'Animal' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

In swift5.x, I want to use a protocol named Animal with an associatedType 'T'.

```
class Shape {
    func transform() {
        print("Shape transofrm")
    }
}

protocol Animal {
    associatedtype T: Shape
    var tansformT: T { get set }
    func bark()
}

var a: any Animal
```

`Rectangle` and `Circle` implements the `Shape` protocol:

```
class Rectangle: Shape {
    override func transform() {
        print("Rectangle transofrm")
    }
}

class Circle: Shape {
    override func transform() {
        print("Circle transofrm")
    }
}
```

And there are two class implements `Animal` protocol:

```
class Dog : Animal {
    var tansformT: Rectangle = Rectangle()
    func bark() {

    }
}

class Cat: Animal {
    var tansformT = Circle()
    func bark() {
        print("Cat bark")
    }
}
```

I want to declare a variable `ani`, it can be `Dog` or `Cat` according the condition, so i try this:

```
var a = 10
var ani: Animal
if a == 10 {
    ani = Cat()
} else {
    ani = Dog()
}
```

then the compiler reports an error:
`Protocol 'Animal' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`
I have try my best for 3+ hours, I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Here I found an answer that can help you out.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59330536/17286292

Failed with error:
**Protocol 'Animal' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements**

```
var ani: Animal = Cat()
```

But change to **opaque** result type like this, it will work.

```
var ani: some Animal = Cat()
```

Doc: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OpaqueTypes.html

From doc:

```
    struct Square: Shape {
        var size: Int
        func draw() -> String {
            let line = String(repeating: "*", count: size)
            let result = Array<String>(repeating: line, count: size)
            return result.joined(separator: "\n")
        }
    }

    func makeTrapezoid() -> some Shape {
        let top = Triangle(size: 2)
        let middle = Square(size: 2)
        let bottom = FlippedShape(shape: top)
        let trapezoid = JoinedShape(
            top: top,
            bottom: JoinedShape(top: middle, bottom: bottom)
        )
        return trapezoid
    }
    let trapezoid = makeTrapezoid()
    print(trapezoid.draw())
    // *
    // **
    // **
    // **
    // **
    // *
```

> The makeTrapezoid() function in this example declares its return type
> as some Shape; as a result, the function returns a value of some given
> type that conforms to the Shape protocol, without specifying any
> particular concrete type. Writing makeTrapezoid() this way lets it
> express the fundamental aspect of its public interface—the value it
> returns is a shape—without making the specific types that the shape is
> made from a part of its public interface.

Comment: thanks, @Nekias, your answer is awesome. Maybe I didn't express my scenario clearly, so I change the question. I want to set `ani` to a different object as some condition. If you know how to do this, please give me the help, I will select your answer.